# pyspark: sort in reduceByKey error: in <lambda> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code: for each `my_id`, I am trying to sort the `amount` field based on the `timestamp` field:

```
output_rdd = my_df.rdd.map(lambda r: (r['my_id'], [r['timestamp'],[r['amount']]]))\
                        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: sorted(a+b, key=(a+b)[0]))\
                        .map(lambda r: r[1])
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 52, ph-hdp-prd-dn02): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/0/yarn/nm/usercache/phanalytics-test/appcache/application_1474532589728_2983/container_e203_1474532589728_2983_01_000014/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/data/0/yarn/nm/usercache/analytics-test/appcache/application_1474532589728_2983/container_e203_1474532589728_2983_01_000014/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2371, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2371, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
  File "/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1792, in combineLocally
  File "/data/0/yarn/nm/usercache/phanalytics-test/appcache/application_1474532589728_2983/container_e203_1474532589728_2983_01_000014/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 238, in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
  File "<ipython-input-11-ec09929e01e4>", line 6, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what I missed? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following from Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html?highlight=sort#key-functions) -

The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.

Convert the arguments passed to key into a python function or a lambda function and try again.

Answer (score 1):

`key` should be a function. Try

```
...     .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: sorted(a+b, key=lambda x: x[0] )) \
```